# Adobe echosign , Sending a Document and retriving it's status

Tags: php, json, curl, echosign

I have Researched Too much before i asked here , i know adobe has a fantastic api , but it could't help me in this .
I am trying to make a php application whic will :

1.Fill Pdf Form with data i already have from a form in my website

2.Send it to echosign to be signed by user ( I have His email )

3.Get Status of the document (Send , Recived, Read)

I know it done With CURL , and the thing that i was able to do is to get all documents send with my account By

```
$ch = curl_init("https://api.na1.echosign.com:443/api/rest/v5/agreements");

$accesstoken = 'XXXXXXXXXX';

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
  'Access-Token:'.$accesstoken
));

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);  

$output = curl_exec($ch);

curl_close($ch);

$decoded = json_decode($output);

var_dump($decoded);
```

It Will Output The Agreements that i sent .
Thanks In Advance !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think what you are asking is a way to create an agreement through Adobe Sign with some formfields, send it to user for signing and then get its status. To achieve this you will have to make the following API calls -

- Create an agreement through **[POST /agreeements](https://secure.na1.echosign.com/public/docs/restapi/v5#!/agreements/)** API, here you can provide location of the formfields and there values if they are known before hand, you can also specify callbackInfo if required so that your system gets alerted if any action is made on the agreement. On successfully exicution of this API call, Adobe Sign will create an agreement with the specified formfiled and send it to the sender specified in the recipientInfo for signing. As a response of this call you will get an agreementId which can be used later on for fetching further details specific to that agreement.
- To get the status of the created agreement use [**GET /agreement/{agreementId}**](https://secure.na1.echosign.com/public/docs/restapi/v5#!/agreements/_0_1_2) API call, where the agreementId is the one received as a response of POST /agreement API call.

Hope this solves your problem.

Comment: I used Docusign for the job , but after i finished i checked your answer and it Worked !